# iOS - can I start "Magnifier" app programmatically?

Tags: ios, iphone, fast-app-switching

I have a camera app and am interested in offering the user the ability to zoom, freeze frame and use camera flash. Very similar to magnifier app. Just so I don't re-invent the wheel:

**Is there a way to programmatically start a native iOS app, like Magnifier (available from control center)?**

I know iOS allows the user to open links in Safari.